# How to override (not the OOP override) the output of System.out.print()?

Tags: java

Is there a way I can override the `System.out.print()`'s output?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
System.out.print("A B C D E F G H I J K L");
```

Will print : `A B C D E F G H I J K L`

Now I want to write a method which overrides this output from a specific position. Something like,

```
override(7, "X Y Z");
```

Should output

```
A B C X Y Z G H I J K L
```

These should happen right in the console.

Comment: This may depend on what terminal program is being used. I suppose someone might have written a Java library that abstracts that (it's probably not in the SDK, though).

Comment: spent 10 seconds on the second line trying to figure out whats so special :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out` is an output stream.  Once you put something in, you can't go in after it and change it.  Even if you could, it is just a byte representation at that point.  The closest you're going to come is making the modification before you send the data to standard out, or wrapping the console such that you capture the data on the other side.

Answer (score 11):

1. create your own `PrintStream` - e.g. `public class YourPrintStream extends PrinterStream`.
2. override the `print(String s)` method and change the string there any way you like. Then call `super.print(s))`;
3. Call [`System.setOut(new YourPrintStream())`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29)

Then everytime `System.out.println` is called, the passed string will be under your control before going into the actual stream.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what will i put inside write() method to achieve my objective?

Comment: Its an almost simple string manipulation. At least give it a try yourself.

Comment: Hey Bozho, great idea. if I set both System.err and System.out to this new print stream, is there any way to tell from within the `print(String s)` method whether it was `System.err` or `System.out` making the call?

Comment: No. That's why you have to set separate streams. 
(Well, technically, there is - you can analyze the current thread stacktrace, but that's hacky)

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever have to modify the same line that you are currently writing, you can write the character "\r" which repositions the cursor at the beginning of the line without advancing to the next line.  From there, you can rewrite the entire line.  For example:

```
A B C D E F G\rA B C X Y
```

would probably display (on a UNIX-ish system, at least)

```
A B C X Y F G
```

If you need cross-platform-ness or editing of older lines, you're probably starting to get into the territory of a [Curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library))-like library.  I can't suggest any specific ones for Java there, but you can take a look around...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [System.setOut()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)) method.

Comment: @kgiannakakis - good answer ... but that's not what he is asking.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you use an interceptor if using ejbs or use an aop aspect.

Each call made to System.out could be intercepted before actually putting the string into it.